# wordpress class file get $_GET

Tags: php, wordpress, class

Working on something and I`m stuck at a point.

I've got a class file that loads when on a page in wordpress.
what I want to do is look for `$_GET` vars if they are present and if they are then call a function in my class.

I`m using a constructor at the top of my class if that helps.

Anyway I can do that ?
his is my __construct thing at the start of my class

```
class mijireh_class extends wpsc_merchant
{
function __construct( $purchase_id = null, $is_receiving = false ) {
    $this->name = __( 'Mijjireh', 'wpsc_gold_cart' );
    parent::__construct( $purchase_id, $is_receiving );

    if(!class_exists('Mijireh')) {
        require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mijireh'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mijireh.php';
    }

    add_action('init', array(&$this, 'mijireh_notify'), 10, 2);
}

public function mijireh_notify()
{
    if(isset($_GET['task']) && $_GET['task'] == 'mijireh_notify') {
        print $_GET['task'];
        exit;
             }
     }
}
```

i tried refreshing that page and passing parameters ?task=mijireh_notify&order_number=8001354073961 but its not callngthe function, i got a print and an exit so i should know

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['thing'])) { yourFunc(); }`

Comment: something like
add_action('init', myfunction);

Comment: what michael said should work, just put that in your "init" function, and call the necessary class function if the $_GET variable is present

Answer (score 1):

to act on $_GET data:

```
add_action('init', 'process_get');
//function in your class
function process_get(){
 if(isset($_GET['som_field'])) {
   // process $_GET data here
 }
}
```

do you mean something like this

Comment: i tried and it doesent do anything...updated main post wiith my code